# Span a JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have the following StackedXYAreaChart:
[image]
How do I make my plot span all the way from the left to all the way to the right so that there are no white spaces between the borders of the chart and the plot? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`createStackedAreaChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createStackedAreaChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) method creates a chart having a [`StackedAreaRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/StackedAreaRenderer.html), for which the domain axis is a [`CategoryAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/CategoryAxis.html). You can adjust the appearance using the `setLowerMargin()` and `setUpperMargin()` methods of the axis.